# Regular expression to embed string with backslash and curly braces in more curly braces

Tags: regex, latex, regular-language

This is a [cross-post from TeX](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/539793/string-replacement-in-bibtool), but it did not get any answers there. And since I assume the problem has more to do with my understanding of regular expressions (or better, lack thereof) than with LaTeX itself, StackOverflow may have been the better place to ask to begin with.

I would like to use [BibTool](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/bibtool) (which was written in C, if this is of any consequence here) to enclose some strings in a `bib`-file in curly braces. The test `bib` entry looks like this:

```
@Article{Cite1,
author       = {Adelbert, A.},
date         = {2020},
journaltitle = {A Journal},
title        = {A title with just \textit{Test} structure and some chemistry \ce{CO2}},
number       = {2},
pages        = {1--4},
volume       = {1},
}
```

I have created the following BibTool resource file:

```
resource {biblatex}
preserve.keys = on
preserve.key.case = on
rewrite.rule = {"\\\(.*{.*}\)" "{{\1}}"}
```

The `rewrite.rule` is supposed to be the following:

1. Find all strings within any field that start with `\`, like `\ce{}`, `\textit{}`, etc. This is done by the `\\` at the beginning of the regular expression.
2. When this string is found save the following in a group, denoted by `\(\)`: A random string at the beginning, followed by `{`, a random string, followed by `}`; i.e. the string `textit{Test}`.
3. Write this string back into the same position, but enclose it in a double-set of curly braces `"{{\1}}"`.

What it manages so far:

1. It apparently finds all commands starting with `\`.
2. It saves the strings and writes them back into the file.

So far, the code returns the following

```
@Article{Cite1,
Author       = {Adelbert, A.},
Date         = {2020},
JournalTitle = {A Journal},
Title        = {A title with just {{textit{Test} structure and some chemistry {{ce{CO2}}}}}},
Number       = {2},
Pages        = {1--4},
Volume       = {1},
}
```

You see it finds the strings and puts `{{` at the beginning of each string. Unfortunately, it puts `}}` at the end of the field, **not** the string, so I now have 6 curly braces at the end of the title field. The braces do match, just two of them should be after `{{textit{Test}` not at the very end. I tried various constructions like `rewrite.rule = {"\\\(.*{.*}\)$" "{{\1}}"}`, `rewrite.rule = {"\\\(.*{.*}\) ?$" "{{\1}}"}`, `rewrite.rule = {"\\\(.*{.*}\)*$" "{{\1}}"}` but this all did not work.

When trying to get the `\` back at the beginning of the string, using `rewrite.rule = {"\\\(.*{.*}\)" "{{\\\1}}"}` I get the `\` back, but also thousands of `{}` until I get a `Rewrite limit exceeded` error.

I am not very good with regular expressions and would be happy for any comments.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My approach would use two phases. In the first phase I would process the macro with one argument and replace in the result the \ by a replacement representation (here ##). In the second pahe I simply replace ## by \.

In BibTool this looks as follows:

```
rewrite.rule {"\\\(\([a-zA-Z]+\|.\){[^{}]*}\)" "{##\1}"}
rewrite.rule {"##" "\\"}
```

Note, that in general the task depicted can not be solved with regular expressions...

Answer (score 2):

The behavior of `.*` by default is to match as many characters as possible. This is called 'greedy matching' in regex terms.

Your pattern is likely matching the following on hitting the first `\`:

```
\textit{Test} structure and some chemistry \ce{CO2}}
```

Replacing the text to:

```
{{textit{Test} structure and some chemistry \ce{CO2}}}}
```

And then finding the next \ and replacing:

```
\ce{CO2}}}} becomes {{ce{CO2}}}}}}
```

Total effect:

```
{A title with just \textit{Test} structure and some chemistry \ce{CO2}}

{A title with just {{textit{Test} structure and some chemistry {{ce{CO2}}}}}}
```

To change the behaviour in most regex flavors you can put a `?` after the quantifier: `.*?` to make it 'lazy', that is match the least amount of characters.

Comment: Thank you for this suggestion. Unfortunately, it does not change anything about the output. `?` is actually described in the manual as matching at most one of the preceding character, while `+` matches at least one. Anyway, neither `?` nor `+` in any combination solves the problem.

Comment: Ah, looks like bibtool might not support extended regex, meaning you can't use the ? as a lazy quantifier. Can you try ```\\\[^}]+}``` and see if that works? ```[^}]+``` means one or more characters that are not  ```}```

Comment: I now tried `rewrite.rule = {"\\\(.*{[^}]*}\)" "{{\1}}"}`. Yes, indeed `[^...]` should tell the regex ti look for everything, except the characters in brackets. I know that this works with other characters from experimenting, but when doing it like that I get an "Unexpected end of string" error. I believe that the `}` within brackets is interpreted as closing the first curly brace, but I cannot escape it: `rewrite.rule = {"\\\(.*{[^\}]*}\)" "{{\1}}"}` throws the same error.

Comment: You need to remove the ```.*``` as well: ```"\\\([^\}]*}\)" "{{\1}}"```

Comment: This also throws the same error "ERROR: unexpected end of string. Unmatched ( or \(". Only now, it does not even find the strings anymore and just does not rewrite anything.

Comment: That's strange, you can see the pattern in action here: https://regexr.com/535po. There may be an issue with backslashes, maybe try escaping the other ```}```: ```"\\\([^\}]*\}\)" "{{\1}}"```.

Comment: Yes, I see. I also tried it with the regex capability of Notepad++ to replace the strings and it worked perfectly fine. Unfortunately, Notepad++ (to my knowledge) is not advanced enough store what it finds and write it back in a modified way, but is just able to replace everything it finds with a predefined string. Hence, I cannot use it do what I want, but would need bibtool, which seems to handle regular expressions in an odd way. Maybe I will try to ask the author directly and see if he could help. Thanks for trying anyway.